# Can someone explain why there is a huge difference in speed on Leetcode between using es6 syntax and es5 with typescript?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

```
function threeSum(nums: number[], targetSum: number = 0): number[][] {
  if (nums.length < 3) return [];

  nums = nums.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  const triplets: number[][] = [];
  for (let anchorIndex = 0; anchorIndex < nums.length - 2; anchorIndex++) {
    // Remove any duplicates from anchor position before setting up pointers.
    while (nums[anchorIndex] === nums[anchorIndex - 1]) anchorIndex++;
    let leftPointer: number = anchorIndex + 1;
    let rightPointer: number = nums.length - 1;
    while (leftPointer < rightPointer) {
      const [anchorValue, leftValue, rightValue]: number[] = [
        nums[anchorIndex],
        nums[leftPointer],
        nums[rightPointer],
      ];
      const sum: number = anchorValue + leftValue + rightValue;
      if (sum === targetSum) {
        triplets.push([anchorValue, leftValue, rightValue]);
        // Remove any duplicates after finding the target sum.
        while (nums[leftPointer] === nums[leftPointer + 1]) leftPointer++;
        // Traverse one past current Non duplicate value.
        leftPointer++;
      }
      if (sum > targetSum) rightPointer--;
      if (sum < targetSum) leftPointer++;
    }
  }
  return triplets;
};
```

This produces 156 ms time to handle the problem.  On other hand if I simply replace the top line with

```
const threeSum = (nums: number[], targetSum: number = 0): number[][] => {
```

This almost doubles the time to handle the problem (308 ms). Is there something I should be keeping in mind while using typescript?

Comment: What the length of `nums` argument?

Comment: How you timing it?  Remember functions are hoisted, were as const is not.  So if your timing includes the function definitions it's not doing a true compare.

Comment: Gotcha, I mean, the length of the nums argument was really long.  I believe it was like 1000s long.  But I see, so functions are hoisted meaning they are populated quickly before what is inside is loaded.